# Fails to create publishing site collection in scripted web application

Tags: web-applications, sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

I have a problem on my SharePoint 2013 farm. I have a script to create web applications in my farm, but when I do I cant create publishing site collections within that web application. (Originally posted here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64308/fails-to-create-publishing-site-collection-in-scripted-web-application

So, the environment is setup like this:

1. We are using host headers for the applications.
2. We have BackConnectionHostNames set up in registry.
3. For now we use the Farm admin account to run the app pool.
4. We have mysites setup and apparently working.
5. No search is setup.
6. We have a content type hub setup and apparently working.

So, the symptoms are appearing to me like this:

1. I cannot create publishing site collections in my new host header based web application when I created it from my script. When I go through the GUI to create the publishing site collection it says "working on it" for a while, then presents me with an error while still spinning the "working on it". In the event log there is this to read:

   ```
   Event log message was: 'The site template was not provisioned successfully. Delete this
   site collection in Central Administration, and then create a new site collection.'. 
   Exception was: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Provisioning did not succeed. Details:  
   Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: '' 
   OriginalException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 
   (E_ACCESSDENIED)) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception
   from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   ```
2. If I created the web application from Central Admin GUI I can successfully create a Publishing Portal in it.
3. If I created the web application with my script I can create a team site successfully.

Below follows my script, can anyone see something that's apparently wrong with this? Did I forget something that the CA GUI takes care of?

```
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1)  {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Import-Module WebAdministration -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue



Function CreateWebApplication($WebApplicationURL, $HttpPort, $WebApplicationName,     
                              $ContentDatabase, $ApplicationPoolDisplayName,  
                              $ApplicationPoolIdentity, $ApplicationPoolPassword, 
                              $PortalSuperReader, $PortalSuperUser) {


Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Web Application" -Status "Creating Web Application $WebapplicationURL"

if($WebApplicationURL.StartsWith("http://")) 
{ 
    $HostHeader = $WebApplicationURL.Substring(7) 
    $HTTPPort = "80" 
} 
elseif($WebApplicationURL.StartsWith("https://")) 
{ 
    $HostHeader = $WebApplicationURL.Substring(8) 
    $HTTPPort = "443" 
}

$AppPoolManagedAccount = Get-SPManagedAccount $ApplicationPoolIdentity

$AuthenticationProvider = New-SPAuthenticationProvider –UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication
#Create a new web application using the existing parameters, assign it to the WebApp variable such that object cache user accounts can be configured
$WebApp = New-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool $ApplicationPoolDisplayName -ApplicationPoolAccount $AppPoolManagedAccount.Username -AuthenticationProvider $AuthenticationProvider -Name $WebApplicationName -url $WebApplicationURL -port $HTTPPort -DatabaseName $ContentDatabase -HostHeader $HostHeader

Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Web Application" -Status "Configuring Object Cache Accounts"

#Assign Object Cache Accounts
$WebApp.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = $PortalSuperUser
$WebApp.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = $PortalSuperReader

Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Web Application" -Status "Creating Object Cache User Policies for Web Application"

#Create a New Policy for the Super User
$SuperUserPolicy = $WebApp.Policies.Add($PortalSuperUser, "Portal Super User Account")
#Assign Full Control To the Super User

$SuperUserPolicy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add(
    $WebApp.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole(
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullControl))

#Create a New Policy for the Super Reader
$SuperReaderPolicy = $WebApp.Policies.Add($PortalSuperReader, "Portal Super Reader Account")
#ASsign Full Read to the Super Reader
$SuperReaderPolicy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add(
$WebApp.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole(
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullRead))

Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Web Application" -Status "Updating Web Application Properties"

#Commit changes to the web application
$WebApp.update()

}

CreateWebApplication "http://add.ress.lan" 80 "Intranet 3"
"sp_intranet3_content" "Intranet3 Pool" "sp_farm" "P4sswd!" 
"sp_superreader" "sp_superuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running from SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator. My script is very similar.  Ensure SuperUser and SuperReader accounts exist in AD.

In the error, the URL is blank.

Your script is to create a Classic Mode Web App, not a Claims-based Web App.